# Дополнение или обстоятельство? (2)

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, выбор-варианта, дополнение, обстоятельство

> Крупный дождь в лесу зелёном прошумел по стройным кленам, по лесным
> цветам.

***По кленам, по цветам*** — это дополнение или обстоятельство?
Ребенок обозначил как дополнение. Учитель исправил и снизил оценку.

Comment: Учителю виднее, чем 99% людей на этом форуме. Тут почти нет учителей, а они бы не помешали.
"Вася прошел по цветам". Здесь дополнение, так как естественен вопрос "по чему?" относительно вопросов "где?/как?". "Дождь прошумел по лесным цветам." Невозможно прошуметь (по чему?) поэтому это не дополнение. Остаются только вопросы (где? как?) поэтому обстоятельство. "Дождь ударил по кронам.". Здесь дополнение, так как глагол ударить предполагает объект, по которому бьют.

Comment: @user190920 Там как раз говорится, по чему он прошумел. Нельзя сказать, что это корректно. *По клёнам/цветам* — это уж точно не место, это предмет. Там что-то надо добавить, например: *прошумел, **ударяя** по стройным клёнам, по лесным цветам*.

Comment: *Прошуметь* — издать шум (словарь) => *издал шум по стройным кленам, по лесным цветам*. Нет, так нельзя. Это разговорное упрощение, опущено действие, направленное на клёны и цветы. Такое нельзя использовать для проверки знаний в школе.

Comment: Тут уже ничего невозможно добавить. https://ilibrary.ru/text/3275/p.1/index.html 
Вот от лесу как передовой вестник пронесся свежий ветерок, повеял прохладой в лицо путнику, прошумел по листьям, захлопнул мимоходом ворота в избе и, вскрутя пыль на улице, затих в кустах. [И. А. Гончаров. Обыкновенная история (1847)]

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Знаю, есть такие примеры. Но это всё-равно разговорное упрощение. Нормально ли издавать шум по чём-то? Нет.

Comment: @Уважаемая Ирина! А вы не хотите нам что-нибудь сказать –  "спасибо" хотя бы за ответ и за комментарии. Или еще можно за ответ проголосовать или даже принять его. А то уже нет никакого желания отвечать, если никто  не реагирует и никто не оценивает работу.  А ведь мы очень старались вам помочь.

Answer (score 1):

**Крупный дождь в лесу зелёном прошумел **по стройным кленам, по лесным цветам**.**

1. Из словаря:

ПРОШУМЕТЬ,  св. 1. Издать, произвести шум (при движении). Вдали прошумел поезд. За окнами прошумел ливень.

ШУМЕТЬ, нсв. 1. Издавать, производить шум (1 зн.). Шумело море. Деревья шумят на ветру.

Как известно, шум создается  движением воздушных масс  при  столкновении их с препятствием (так, к примеру, образуются согласные звуки). Поэтому при создании шума  у нас были  **два обязательных участника** – ветер и какой-то материальный объект.

Явным дополнением для «шумовых» глаголов является **беспредложный Т.п**. (с его инструментальным значением), например: шуршать (чем?) бумагой.

При наличии предлога дополнение становится маловероятным. *Деревья шумят* (как?) на ветру.  Здесь обстоятельство образа действия.

*Крупный дождь в лесу зеленом Прошумел (где?) по стройным кленам,
По лесным цветам..*.  Конечно, объект участвовал в создании шума, но в данном случае  это неважно – здесь он скорее **обозначает пространство,** где был слышен шум. Поэтому это **обстоятельство места**.

2. Но снижать оценку в данном случае **неверно** – более подходящей формулировкой здесь будет «**объектное обстоятельство**» (все-таки именно объект обозначил «шумовое» пространство).  Поэтому сомнения при выборе ответа можно считать вполне обоснованными.  И я не думаю, что педагог так уж точно и развернуто объяснил своим ученикам эту сложную тему.  Намного корректнее было бы вместе со школьником обсудить и обосновать свое решение.

Comment: Вот не понимаю это (не согласен). Трава может обозначать место (площадь, ею непрерывно покрытую), но не деревья, это тупо. Дождь бьёт не по пространству, а по предмету. Другое дело, если лингвисты так условились. Есть ссылка, где указано, что по предмету — это место? Тогда можно считать, что в "ударить (где?) по лбу" тоже обстоятельство. Есть уже нормальная фраза: *дождь бьёт по окнам*. Так "шуметь по клёнам" от этого далеко не ушло. Или "по окнам" — это место?

Comment: А у вас ветер, дождь бьют только по верхним листочкам, до нижних не добираются? Вот  любите вы мелкие детали, а общей картины не видите. А здесь только два решения: дополнение или обстоятельство. Кстати, если обстоятельство, то какое?

Comment: Все листочки — это часть дерева. Воспринимаю только как дополнение. Предмет — обстоятельство, если по нём передвигаются либо находятся на нём.

Comment: "Прошуметь по кленам" – это вообще МЕТАФОРА: глаголы "шуметь, прошуметь" не управляют Д.п. с предлогом ПО.  Дословно описание события выглядит так: Ветер  создал шум в пространстве, где растут клены, на некоторое время.

Comment: Нет, думаю, что дождь может шуметь в прямом смысле.

Comment: Это однозначно языковая метафора.  Но в метафорическом плане сочетание можно рассматривать и как ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ: Дождь прошумел (прошел/пробежал с шумом) (по чему?)  по деревьям и цветам.

Comment: Метафора не покрывает несочетаемость с предлогом. Не вижу там метафоры. Где там переносное значение? С чем там аналогия?

Comment: Дождь идет - это уже языковая метафора. А пройти  (с шумом) можно по чему-либо, то есть прошуметь.  Мы считаем предложную форму дополнением, если объект действия выступает на первый план. А здесь шум создается при воздействии водных струй именно на поверхность ЛИСТА, поэтому шум получается ХАРАКТЕРНЫМ.  Теперь что-нибудь проясняется?

Comment: Нет, это не метафора. Словарь: идти 11) Падать, лить (об осадках) *Снег, дождь идёт.* Это стандартное значение. Здесь нет аналогии, что дождь идёт, как человек.

Comment: oleedd, обычно только первое значение является прямым. 1. Двигаться, передвигаться, ступая ногами. Все остальные – переносные, и по происхождению – они языковые метафоры, закрепленные в словаре. Согласны?

Comment: Не очень. Оно не воспринимается как переносное значение. Может, когда-то так и было, но сейчас оно абсолютно стандартное. Идти может совещание, время, передача. Это всё метафоры?

Comment: Да, они метафоры по происхождению, так как все связаны с движением (в пространстве или во времени). Но когда слово закрепляется в словаре, оно меняет статус, приобретает многозначность.  В то же время оно  вписывается в грамматическую систему языка и может управлять только определенным падежом. И вот управление Д.п. с предлогом ПО  для глагола шуметь еще не прописано в языке, но в метафорическом плане это  возможно. Прошуметь в кленовой роще – это обстоятельство места, а прошуметь по листьям – это уже метафора. Возможно, это обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, почту.

Comment: Но "прошуметь" не воспринимается как "пройти с шумом", там ни малейшей коннотации такой нет. То следствие, ведь если дождь есть, то он обязательно идёт. Считаю, что несочетаемость нельзя метафорой покрывать, то разговорное упрощение. Или есть ссылка, где такое явление описано? По происхождению, может быть, метафоры, но сейчас на переносное значение не похоже.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, сделайте окончательный вывод для завершения дискуссии. Это дополнение или обстоятельство? Если обстоятельство, то какое?

Comment: Дополнение, дерево может быть местом, на котором что-то/кто-то находится. но не считаю, что предмет может обозначать площадь удара. Иначе — *ударил (где?) по ноге*. Разве так принято в синтаксисе?

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Надо подумать